# WORD.- Cuadro Combinado Heredado y que permite escritura texto

Tags: vba

Como puedo en WORD, hacer un cuadro combinado heredado y que a su vez permita escribir cuando no quiero seleccionar ninguna de las opciones. He encontrado este código en las preguntas de Microsoft.

```
Sub Populateddfood()
Dim xDirection As FormField
Dim xState As FormField
    On Error Resume Next
Set xDirection = ActiveDocument.FormFields("ddfood")
Set xState = ActiveDocument.FormFields("ddCategory")
If ((xDirection Is Nothing) Or (xState Is Nothing)) Then Exit Sub
With xState.DropDown.ListEntries
    .Clear
    Select Case xDirection.Result
        Case "Fruit"
            .Add "Apple"
            .Add "Banana"
            .Add "Peach"
            .Add "Lychee"
            .Add "Watermelon"
        Case "Vegetable"
            .Add "Cabbage"
            .Add "Onion"
        Case "Meat"
            .Add "Pork"
            .Add "Beef"
            .Add "Mutton"
            .Clear
    End Select
End With
End Sub
```

Pero no sé como cambiar el código para que además pueda escribir.

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Por favor, muestra el código que has utilizado, no pongas enlaces externos, tienes un editor de textos para ello

Comment: Hecho, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si es un cuadro combinado, ¿no te obliga a seleccionar un valor? Quiero decir, que no permite introducir una opción diferente a las mostradas en la lista ¿no?.

Comment: Entiendo que lo que quieres decir, es un desplegable, ahí si que no permite, en el cuadro combinado por lo menos en WORD si que te deja. En Excel no te deja a no ser que hagas el truco de quitar el aviso...en ACCESS no lo he probado. El tema es que esto lo hago para una evaluacion de riesgos, hay riesgos que si estan predefinidos y se pueden poner en WORD en un cuadro combinado pero otros no, y es cuando es necesario escribir.